# Nginx: How to convert post data encoding from UTF-8 to TIS-620 before pass them through proxy

Tags: nginx, lua

I would like to convert POST data received from request and convert it from UTF-8 to TIS-620 before pass it to backend via proxy_pass using code below but I am not sure which way to do it

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://targetwebsite;
}
```

If I am not wrong, I believe I have to use [Lua module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua) to manipulate the request but I don't know if they support any character conversion.

Could anybody help me with sample code to convert POST data from UTF-8 toTIS-620 using LUA and how to validate if POST data is UTF-8 before convert it or if there is other better way to manipulate/convert POST data in nginx ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on Lua 5.1/5.2/5.3

```
local function utf8_to_unicode(utf8str, pos)
   -- pos = starting byte position inside input string
   local code, size = utf8str:byte(pos), 1
   if code >= 0xC0 and code < 0xFE then
      local mask = 64
      code = code - 128
      repeat
         local next_byte = utf8str:byte(pos + size)
         if next_byte and next_byte >= 0x80 and next_byte < 0xC0 then
            code, size = (code - mask - 2) * 64 + next_byte, size + 1
         else
            return
         end
         mask = mask * 32
      until code < mask
   elseif code >= 0x80 then
      return
   end
   -- returns code, number of bytes in this utf8 char
   return code, size
end

function utf8to620(utf8str)
   local pos, result_620 = 1, {}
   while pos <= #utf8str do
      local code, size = utf8_to_unicode(utf8str, pos)
      if code then
         pos = pos + size
         code =
            (code < 128 or code == 0xA0) and code
            or (code >= 0x0E01 and code <= 0x0E3A or code >= 0x0E3F and code <= 0x0E5B) and code - 0x0E5B + 0xFB
      end
      if not code then
         return utf8str  -- wrong UTF-8 symbol, this is not a UTF-8 string, return original string
      end
      table.insert(result_620, string.char(code))
   end
   return table.concat(result_620)  -- return converted string
end
```

Usage:

```
local utf8string = "UTF-8 Thai text here"
local tis620string = utf8to620(utf8string)
```

Comment: Looks like a better solution than mine, because it checks if the characters have an encoding in TIS-620. And it recognizes the no-break space. Doesn't do complete validation of the UTF-8 (for instance, rejecting overlong sequences), but that may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the encoding on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_Industrial_Standard_620-2533) and came up the following solution for converting from UTF-8 to TIS-620. It assumes that all the codepoints in the UTF-8 string have an encoding in TIS-620. It will work if the UTF-8 string only contains ASCII printable characters (codepoints `" "` to `"~"`) or Thai characters (codepoints `"ก"` to `"๛"`). Otherwise, it will give wrong and possibly very strange results.

This assumes you have Lua 5.3's `utf8` library or an equivalent. If you're using an earlier version of Lua, one possibility is the [pure-Lua version](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Scribunto/tree/master/includes/engines/LuaCommon/lualib/ustring) of the `ustring` library from MediaWiki (used by Wikipedia and Wiktionary, for instance). It provides a function to validate UTF-8, and many of the other functions will validate strings automatically. (That is, they throw an error if the string is invalid UTF-8.) If you use that library, you just have to replace `utf8.codepoint` with `ustring.codepoint` in the code below.

```
-- Add this number to TIS-620 values above 0x80 to get the Unicode codepoint.
-- 0xE00 is the first codepoint of Thai block, 0xA0 is the corresponding byte used in TIS-620.
local difference = 0xE00 - 0xA0

function UTF8_to_TIS620(UTF8_string)
    local TIS620_string = UTF8_string:gsub(
      '[\194-\244][\128-\191]+',
      function (non_ASCII)
          return string.char(utf8.codepoint(non_ASCII) - difference)
      end)
    return TIS620_string
end
```